# What does phi mean in this context?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

In an article on [Selection Bias in A/B Testing](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/selection-bias-in-online-experimentation-c3d67795cceb), AirBnB proposes a solution to their own estimated bias. This solution is to subtract from the aggregated effect a bias estimate, captured by this equation:
$$
\hat{\beta} = \sum_{i=1}^n W_i \phi \left( \frac{W_i b_i - X_i}{W_i} \right)
$$
where

> $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are random variables defined on a same probability space, and each $X_i$ follows a distribution with finite mean $a_i$ and finite variance $\sigma_i^2$ (the distributions are not necessarily identical.) We regard $a_i$ as the unknown true effect and usually estimate it by the unbiased estimate $X_i$;
>
> $b_i$ is the cut-off from the reference distribution for significance level $\alpha_i$, usually set at $0.05$; and
>
> $W_i$ is the estimated standard deviation of $X_i$, to define the bias estimate

In this context, what does $\phi$ stand for? My current understanding (by separating the two terms inside the parenthesis into
$$
b_i - X_i / W_i
$$
is that they're calculating the individual bias estimates as the difference between the cutoff and "how many" standard deviations fit into the estimate. Then they're adding these up, but I don't know what $W_i\phi$ is doing inside the sum.

Comment: The phi coefficient is a correlation between two variables.

Comment: So, the equation states that Wi is correlated to the expression in parenthesis, but it does not affect the actual sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [paper](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/3220000/3219905/p491-lee.pdf?ip=119.74.62.246&id=3219905&acc=OPENTOC&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E054E54E275136550&__acm__=1543596371_0eb9cf1c3a55243b2244557e097d0783), $\phi$ refers to the density function of standard normal distribution.

Let me include some details:

They use the following result:

> Suppose $Z$ follows standard normal distribution, then
>
> $$f_{Z|Z\ge t}(s) = \frac{\phi(s)}{1-\Phi(t)}$$
> and hence
> $$E[Z|Z \ge t]=\frac{\int_t^\infty s\phi(s)\, ds}{1-\Phi(t)}=\frac{-\int_t^\infty \phi'(s)\, ds}{1-\Phi(t)}=\frac{\phi(t)}{1-\Phi(t)}$$

Assuming $X_i$ follows normal distribution $N(a_i, \sigma_i^2)$.
\begin{align}
&\beta = E[S_A-T_A] \\&=\sum_{i=1}^nE[I((X_i-a_i)>(b_i\sigma_i-a_i))(X_i-a_i)]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i E\left[I\left(\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}>\frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right)\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_iP\left(\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}>\frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right)E\left[\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\left|\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma}>\frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma}\right.\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i P\left(\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}>\frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right)\frac{\phi\left( \frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right)}{P\left(\frac{X_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}>\frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right)} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i \phi\left( \frac{b_i\sigma_i-a_i}{\sigma_i}\right)\\
\end{align}

They then replace some parameters via estimation.